# Image is not displaying PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, pyqt4

I have written this code that actually changes the image when button is clicked.

```
#Make sure you have Winter.jpg image file relative to this script file.
#Code runs fine in python idle, eric.


import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Test', 10))
        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

        # Show  image
        self.pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.pic.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 400)
        self.pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Picture1.png").scaledToWidth(64))


        # Show button
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.clicked.connect(self.fun)
        btn.move(50, 50)


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 2000, 1500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')
        self.show()

    # Connect button to image updating
    def fun(self):
        self.pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap( "icon_contribution.png"))

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: Picture 1]

**Picture 1**

[image]

**Picture 2**

this code is running fine and showing the images for Picture 1 but it is not showing the image for when i specify picture 2. I don't know what is exactly problem. How can i show the second image using PyQt4.

Comment: both pictures are displayed without problem here. Only thing to pay attention for is that Picture 1 is a PNG while Picture two is a JPG. So I guess you probably forgot to change the extension in your code

Comment: I did change. How is it working for you ? What python version are you using ? Are you using PyQt4?

Comment: @jps i did change the extensions name in my code.

Comment: glad to hear it works. Jsut to answer your questions: I use Python 2.7.13 and PyQt4.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with my Compiler. I used PyScripter which resulted in this problem, when i changed the compiler it worked fine.